# how to check the data is arrived on TCP socket?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip, port

```
SOCKET sock;
SOCKET fd;
uint8* pChunkData;
uint16 chunkLen;
uint16 port = 52428;


void CreateSocket() {
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int len;
    int iResult;

    u_long iMode = 0;
    int sockoptval = 1;

    printf("Initializing Winsock\n");

    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD (1, 1);
    iResult =  WSAStartup (wVersionRequested, &wsaData);      
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n"); 

    // create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
        //return 0;
    }

    printf("Socket Created\n");

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&sockoptval, 1);

    iResult = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", iResult);

    // create socket address of the server
    memset( &server, 0, sizeof(server));

    // IPv4 - connection
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // accept connections from any ip adress
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    // set port
    server.sin_port = htons(52428);

    //Binding between the socket and ip address
    if(bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }


    //Listen to incoming connections
    if(listen(sock, 3) == -1) {
        printf("Listen failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Server has been successfully set up - Waiting for incoming connections");

    for(;;) {
        len = sizeof(client);
        fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

        if (fd < 0){
        printf("Accept failed");
        //closesocket(sock);
        }
        //echo(fd);

        printf("\n Process incoming connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),ntohs(client.sin_port));
    }
}

void main() {
    HANDLE h1,h2,h3;
    int bytes_recieved;

    double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;

    pChunkData = &recv_data;
    chunkLen = sizeof(pChunkData);

    CreateSocket();

    while(1) {
        bytes_recieved = recv(fd, recv_data, 100 , 0 );
        recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
    }                         
    XcpIp_RxCallback (chunkLen, *pChunkData, port);
}
```

The above is a server side program and it is accepting a connection from the master. I want to call
`XcpIp_RxCallback (chunkLen, *pChunkData, port);` the API, whenever I receive a data on the socket `fd`. Could anyone tell me how to do that ??

Comment: What about putting `if (bytes_recieved>0) XcpIp_RxCallback (...);` into the loop?

Comment: Well, you have another infinite loop `for(;;)` in `CreateSocket`. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: it is keep on accepting the incoming connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense.

Your CreateSocket() method loops forever accepting connections and ignoring them, so the code after the call to it in main() that reads from a socket is unreachable.

You should spawn a thread for each accepted socket that does the I/O for that session.

If you get an error on any system call, just printing a string without even the actual error, and then proceeding as though the error hadn't happened, is not sufficient mitigation.

There is no point in this code in setting the listening socket into non-blocking model

Answer (score 0):

fork or thread off the 'while(1) {..recv()..} loop.